# Why were the Dragon Knights trying to kill the Dragon Torc?

Tags: noein

In [Noein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noein), there is a bit of complicated quantum-type stuff going on.  There are multiple timespaces that are possible futures for the "real" world (which is a possible present timespace).  The commonality between all worlds seems to be Haruka (a.k.a. the Dragon Torc).  If I interpreted this correctly, this means that anything she observes becomes the actual outcome.

So, one of the timespaces (La'cryma) decides that they want to sacrifice the Dragon Torc.  Wouldn't this cause mass chaos and some kind of crazy quantum status of the timespaces since the observer can no longer definitively confirm any outcome (i.e. mass [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume what they were hoping for is that Noein would no longer be able to attain Haruka and confirm the existence of Shangri La, with the hopeful outcome.  As stated in the show, no one knows what would happen if Haruka was killed.  Any and all futures would be possible, confirming their own dimensions existence and stopping its destruction.

My problem with the 'observer' idea is that she saw Lacryma first, wouldn't that confirm its existence above Shangri La's?

Comment: I disagree with the comments, this is a good answer.